# Can Bayesian credible intervals adjust for multiple testing?

Tags: regression, bayesian, multiple-comparisons

I am doing some bayesian regression and need to compute credible intervals for pairwise comparisons. I am wondering if the techniques for multiple testing (e.g. Bonferroni/Tukey HSD) are still appropriate in the Bayesian framework?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the discussion on the linked page doesn't answer your question, please pose a more detailed question that describes just what isn't clear.